# Recv ring buffer vs simple buffer

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, circular-buffer

I'm working on a client-server app. My app is working with variable size packets, each packet has a header and a payload of variable length.

My dilemma is what is the best approach for handing the packets when doing recv.
Most of the tutorials I've came across suggest using a ring buffer but as far as I can tell it's more efficient to use a buffer whose size is twice the size of the biggest packet you can handle.

If I use a ring buffer I need an additional buffer for recv and then I need to copy the buffer in the ring buffer which means I need to do one or two memcpys to insert the buffer in the ring buffer

If I use the single buffer approach I only need one buffer which I can pass to recv call and a memmove call to move data to the start of the buffer when I got a full packet and there still is data belonging to another packet in the buffer.

Am I getting something wrong ?

PS. If you can point me to any source code/example where variable length packets are handled that would be helpful.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath  it's TCP

Answer (score 1):

> If I use a ring buffer I need an additional buffer for recv and then I need to copy the buffer in the ring buffer which means I need to do one or two memcpys to insert the buffer in the ring buffer

Yeah, two reads and writes, no big deal (*). But you don't need an additional buffer. For read just maximize read to the space left till the end of the ring buffer.

(*): If you are worried about the cost of additional syscall, for scatter/gather read/write there is `recvmsg` and `sendmsg`.

Comment: yes I could call recv with len = free space of ring buffer but that would mean I lose some throughput as I could end calling recv with very small values for the length parameter

Comment: see (*). and it probably doesn't matter. these kind of optimizations only matter in extremely high performance servers.

Comment: you are right. But I still don't understand what are the advantages of using a ring buffer over a simple buffer